# Llenar tabla con Select mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Buenas tardes, necesito llenar un datatable de jquery con los datos traídos desde un select con el filtro de un parámetro, seleccionas el filtro desde un checkbox y al presionar un botón despliega los datos en la tabla
La consulta funciona, pero al mostrar los datos no funciona, algún ejemplo de cómo realizarlo?
Estoy desarrollando en php + mysql + patrón mvc, adjunto código con consulta

Consulta

```
function filtroMed($rut)
{
    global $gbd;
    $_SESSION['con'] = $rut;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM atencion WHERE rutMedico ='".$rut."'";
    $res=$gbd->query($sql);
    if($res)
    {
        $row=$res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $row;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Controlador

```
elseif($_POST['tipo']=='medico')
{
    if($medico->filtroMed($_POST['rut']))
    {
        header('Location: http://localhost/dashboard/Cesfam/Vista/mostrarEstadistica.php?med=si');
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: http://localhost/dashboard/Cesfam/Vista/mostrarEstadistica.php?med=no');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Este código es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Usa sentencias preparadas en lugar de generar consultas de manera dinámica concatenando valores

Comment: Lo de que es vulnerable a inyeccion es relativo, todo depende de donde salga $rut.  Puedes añadir como muestras la tabla??

Answer (score 1):

Antes de nada, tu consulta tiene problemas de seguridad, prueba a usar algo así

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('
  SELECT
    *
  FROM atencion 
  WHERE
    rutMedico= :rut
  LIMIT 1
  ');

$sth->bindParam(':ruta', $ruta);

$sth->execute();

$records= $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con recomendación, sin embargo ten presente anexar un  aporte a resolver el problema actual.

Answer (score 1):

La verdad no entiendo muy bien como estas operando, debes entender que al usar el `header("Location: ...")` estas enviando al usuario la información necesaria en el encabezado HTTP para que tu navegador sepa hacia donde debe apuntar, osea en otras palabras el cliente (navegador) quien redirige teniendo en cuenta la información que le suministraste a través de la cabecera:

> http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php
>
> > ...header() es usado para enviar encabezados HTTP sin formato.
> >
> > "Location:" No solamente envía el encabezado al navegador, sino que también devuelve el código de status (302) REDIRECT al navegador a no ser que el código de status 201 o 3xx ya haya sido enviado.

Sabiendo lo anterior, entonces puedes deducir que no es equivalente a incluir el archivo, como lo harías con `require`o `include`

Suponiendo que tengas estos dos ficheros:

-- principal.php

```
<?php 
$miVariable = "hola mundo";
header("archivo-final.php");
```

-- archivo-final.php

```
<?php
echo $miVariable;
```

Notaras que al ejecutar el archivo `principal.php` finalmente terminas tambien ejecutando el `archivo-final.php` con el siguiente mensaje de error es:

> **Notice:** Undefined variable: miVariable in **archivo-final.php** on line ...

Esto es porque lo que realmente esta sucediendo, no es que llames a tu fichero `archivo-final.php` desde `principal.php`, sino que le has dicho al usuario que una vez tenga la respuesta del servidor respecto a la consulta `principal.php` se dirija a `archivo-final.php`, es como si el usuario mismo escribiese la URL del `archivo-final.php` directamente en la barra de navegación (*dos consultas independientes*). Ahora si lo anterior es claro y acierto al pensar que estas tratando de usar la variable `$datos` en el fichero `mostrarEstadistica.php`, ese sería tu problema, bastaría con editar el `header` por un `require` o `include`, así:

```
elseif($_POST['tipo']=='medico')
{
    if($medico->filtroMed($_POST['rut']))
    {
        $_GET['med'] = 'si';
    }
    else
    {
        $_GET['med'] = 'si';
    }
    require('__RUTA_VISTA__/mostrarEstadistica.php');
}
```

Edite ligeramente el código, puesto que sin importar si se cumple o no el filtro, siempre ejecutas linea que llama a la  vista y lo único que cambia es el atributo `$_GET` que le enviás. Por ello no vale la pena incluirla en el condicional.

A considerar:

- `__RUTA_VISTA__` es la ruta relativa o absoluta del directorio que almacena a mostrarEstadistica.php.
- No creo que sea optimo usar directamente las variables globales `$_POST` y `$_GET` de hecho el uso `$_GET` es innecesario en este caso, pero trato de mantener la estructura actual. En cuanto al acceso a variables globales puedes usar filter_input(...) pero es otra temática.